# Game Slowed by Particles in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am developing an XNA game and am trying to improve the performance of the game by hiding objects that are not visible to the user.

My first thought was to use a `BoundingFrustum` based on the camera's view and projection matrices, and then only draw objects whose `BoundingBox` collides or is inside the frustum. However, trying to do this gave me very unpredictable results, with objects disappearing before going out of view and sometimes not showing at all at certain camera angles.

Has anyone else implemented a successful solution to improve their game's performance?

Comment: Are you sure such changes actually improve performance? I suspect that XNA's rendering code [clips to the view volume](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Clipping) already.

Comment: I agree with @Anko. You first need to determine if you actually have a performance problem and what code is causing it. There might be a few different things going on. That said, I think you have the right idea, post the code for what you're currently doing and we can help you fix it.

Comment: I currently have a particle system that consists of simple planes facing the camera. If there is no battle, the particle count is about 150. But during a battle, the number of particles can easily reach 500 with all of the smoke, explosions, and exhaust trails.

Comment: I have reduced the lifetime of smoke particles, and the count has dropped to 400 during a battle. However, the frame rate is still stuttering and remaining about 15 fps.

Comment: is this a 2d or 3d game?

Comment: @Jon It's a 3D game.

Comment: Are you sure it is the number of particles is the problem? Drawing 400 particles doesn't sound like very much. How is your draw loop organised? Are the particles instantiated or are you pushing each particle mesh each time, number of draw calls etc.?

Comment: Number of particles was part of the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a multi-faceted solution to my performance problem.

1. I have reduced the lifetimes of particles so they disappear more quickly.
2. I have reduced the number of emitters by almost 25%.
3. I have implemented  some code to decide whether to draw the particle:

   ```
   if (distance > 600) { continue; }
   if (distance > 300 && distance < 600) { 
     if (Math.Round(distance) == Math.Truncate(distance)) { continue; }
   }
   ```
4. Not particle related, but I prevented smaller objects, like fighters, from being drawn since they are obscured by HUD icons. These models usually have ~20k polys with a 2048x2048 texture.

This prevents all particles further than 600 units from the camera being drawn (since they are too small to be seen), and randomly reduces the number of particles between 300 and 600 being drawn (since additional particles at that distance adds no detail).

This has greatly increased the frame rate and makes the game very smooth even in large battles. Number two was by far the biggest improvement.

Comment: Say, are you face particles to the camera by recreating planes each frame or using shader? If first then you can improve performance using shader instead.

Comment: @Silveor, Good point. I am recreating planes each frame. I also have little experience with shaders. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might also want to consider future-proofing techniques by adding the option to increase / decrease particle density in a "Graphics Options" setting, as performance may also rely on the machine's capabilities to render `X` number of graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [billboarding](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Billboarding.php) technique for particles.

<s>Also you can check [my old ugly test project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-4sbCAUVHrzVnhvcDZuRi1LWDg/view?usp=sharing). It somehow works and contains particle shader.</s>

**UPDATE**

This system was real ugly and slow so I rewrite it:

1. Particle is simple object that has positions, velocity scale and lifetime.
2. Particle emitter is object that has link to particle manager, bounds and emit function.
3. Particle manager is object that keep list of particles and dictionary of emitters.

All particles drawing in one draw call and using special shader.

1. I create special vertex with fields Position, TexCoord and Index.
2. I create mesh with 50 rectangles from (-0.5,-0.5,0) to (-0.5,-0.5,0) using this special vertex class and each 6 vertices (each rectangle) have same index. This mesh never recreated and used for rendering of all particles.
3. To shader I pass rotation transform based on camera rotation and array of 50 transforms. Rotation transform turn all rectangles to face to the camera.
4. Each vertex has index. In vertex shader position should be multiplied on rotation transform and it own transform from passed transforms array.

So, to draw all particles I use same mesh but in cicle pass each next 50 transforms until all particles was drawn. Each frame recalculates only rotation matrix once for all particles and transform matrix for eache perticle.

Also composing all particle textures in one will texture increase performance.

So, I tested it with simple one pixel texture and have 60 FPS with 10K and about 20 FPS with 30K particles in my voxel game on my Lenovo G555 (2.2 GHz; Radeon HD 4550).